# Create dynamic SQL based on column names passed through a string

Tags: join, azure-sql-database, left-join, dynamic-sql

I need to find out rows that are present in table A and missing from table B (using LEFT JOIN) wherein table A and table B are two tables with same structure but within different schema.
But the query has to be constructed using Dynamic SQL and the columns that need to be used for performing JOIN are stored in a string. How to extract the column names from string and use them to dynamically construct below query :

Database is Azure SQL Server

eg :

```
DECLARE @ColNames NVARCHAR(150) = 'col1,col2'
```

Query to be constructed based on columns defined in ColNames :-

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A
Left Join
Table B
ON A.col1 = B.col1
AND A.col2 = B.col2
AND B.col1 IS NULL AND B.col2 IS NULL
```

If the number of columns in `@ColNames` is more then the SELECT statement needs to cater for all the column.

Comment: I  am using  Azure SQL Server

Comment: Could you provide how the dynamic sql is currently being build up? Where are the tables coming from? Why do you use `left join` instead of `not exists`?

Comment: I can use not exists as well but again the correlated sub query will need to match column values for all the columns present in string variable like : Select * from Table A Where Not Exists (Select 1 From Table B Where TableB.Col1  = TableA.Col1 And TableB.Col2 = TableA.Col2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the full context, try this:

```
DECLARE @ColNames NVARCHAR(150) = 'col1,col2'
DECLARE @JoinContion NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @WhereCondition NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @JoinContion += CONCAT('[a].', QUOTENAME(Value), ' = ', '[b].', QUOTENAME(Value), (CASE WHEN LEAD(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Value) IS NOT NULL THEN ' AND ' ELSE '' END))
    ,@WhereCondition += CONCAT('[a].', QUOTENAME(Value), ' IS NULL', (CASE WHEN LEAD(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Value) IS NOT NULL THEN ' AND ' ELSE '' END))
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ColNames,N',')

SELECT @JoinContion, @WhereCondition
```

- **String_Split**: To split the input string into columns
- **Lead**: to determine if we need the `AND` keyword when it's not the last row.

*Be aware the `NOT EXISTS` is probably a better solution then `LEFT JOIN`*