# SQL - How to use Comma separated column values in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table called Configuration. It contains the values like below,

```
Id  SourceColumns   TargetColumns   SourceTable TargetTable
1   Name, Age       CName, CAge     STable       TTable 
2   EId             EmplId          EmpTable     TTable
```

In a stored procedure, I have to get the column names from the above table and I have to compare the source table and target table.

I am able to do that easily for the 2nd record as it has only one column name, so in the where clause I can write sourcecolumn = targetcolumn like,

```
SELECT 
       EId
    ,  EmplId
FROM 
      EmpTable E
      JOIN TTable T ON E.Eid = T.EmplId
```

The first record in the table has 2 columns separated by comma (,).

I have to compare like this,

```
SELECT 
       Name
    ,  Age 
FROM 
      STable S 
      JOIN TTable T ON S.Name = T.CName AND S.Age = T.CAge
```

In some cases the source columns and target columns may have more column names separated by comma(,)

Please help me on this.

Comment: I'd say, change your data model. There should be no comma-separated data in a relational database. We have *tables* for this. Add a table `configuration_columns (id, id_configuration, source_column, target_column)` and you're set.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225213/create-dynamic-sql-based-on-column-names-passed-through-a-string/63226778#63226778

Comment: In addition to what  @ThorstenKettner says, it appears that you are storing object names in the table, therefore, I *assume* using it to generate dynamic statements. Such "configuration" tables normally denote a large underlying design flaw or a severe lack of understanding of the design of the database. Either the table isn't needed, and you should be writing the statements properly, or you need to learn the design of the database.

Comment: Thank you so much @ThorstenKettner for your design suggestion. My requirement is below,  I am building a reconciliation system and it actually compare the source data and target data. There are many situations I need to compare more than one columns from source and target tables. That is the reason I would like to store the column names as a comma separated string and use that while comparing the tables.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Thank you so much for your example, I hope I can use that in my code. I am worrying whether the design I made is right or wrong because of the people comments

Comment: @Larnu I am building a SQL reconciliation system and it actually compares the source data and target tables. So I have to store the table names and column names in a table. If the current design is not good, could you please suggest a proper design so that I can compare the tables with dynamic column names.

Comment: *"So I have to store the table names and column names in a table."* They're already stored in tables; it's the `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` objects.

Comment: Every time you concatenate lists to store them in a columns your design is wrong in a RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu, I think I didnt convey properly. I am trying again. I am building a reconciliation system. The source and target data can be anything like API, SQL DB, Active Directory, Excel and etc... The front-end is .NET C#.  I just get the data from any of the data sources and storing in SQL on the fly. Then I compare the data in SQL Server. The source data will be stored in SQL in a new table, the target data will be stored in a new table. The comparison column input from the user. I use the columns to match the source and target, send back the differences to front-end.

Comment: Notice how 2 of your column names are singular (sourceTable, TargetTable) and 2 of them are plural?  The plural named columns are the problem.  The data should be "normalized" into separate tables.  Instead of SourceColumns column, create a new SourceColumns table with fk on ID referencing back to Configuration table.

Comment: The _select list_ in your first example query returns data from both tables, but without using table aliases. That will be problematic when the column name is the same in both tables. The second example query returns data from only the source table. How is that decision made? Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner your example works great and the one which I was looking were given by you. With so much happy I tried in test environment and found that SQL Server versions was 2014. So it is working in dev and not in test. Now I have to find any simple alternates for STRING_AGG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know whether you have completely understood the data model I suggested in the request comments and in order to properly answer the question:

Your table is not normalized, as the data in the columns `SourceColumns` and `TargetColumns` is not atomic. And one even has to interpret the data (the separator is the comma and the nth element in one column relates to the nth element in the other column).

This is how your tables should look like instead (the create statements are pseudo code):

```
create table configuration_tables
(
 id_configuration_tables int,
 source_table text,
 target_table text,
 primary key (id_configuration_tables),
 unique key (source_table),
 unique key (target_table) -- or not? in your sample two souce table map to the same target table
);

create table configuration_columns
(
 id_configuration_columns int,
 id_configuration_tables int,
 source_column text,
 target_column text,
 primary key (id_configuration_columns),
 foreign key (id_configuration_tables) references configuration_tables (id_configuration_tables)
);
```

Your sample data would then become

### configuration_tables

```
id_configuration_tables | source_table | target_table
------------------------+--------------+-------------
1                       | STable       | TTable
2                       | EmpTable     | TTable
```

### configuration_columns

```
id_configuration_columns | id_configuration_tables | source_column | target_column
-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------
1                        | 1                       | Name          | CName
2                        | 1                       | Age           | CAge
3                        | 2                       | EId           | EmplId
```

As of SQL Server 2017 you can use `STRING_AGG` to create your queries is. In earlier versions this was also possible with some `STRING_AGG` emulation you will easily find wit Google or SO.

```
select 
  'select s.' + string_agg (c.source_column + ', t.' + c.target_column, ', ') +
  ' from ' + t.source_table + ' s' +
  ' join ' + t.target_table + ' t' +
  ' on ' + string_agg('t.' + c.target_column + ' = s.' + c.source_column, ' and ') +
  ';' as query
from configuration_tables t
join configuration_columns c on c.id_configuration_tables = t.id_configuration_tables
group by t.source_table, t.target_table
order by t.source_table, t.target_table;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8866b2485ba9bba92c2391c67bb8cae0